# JSF - <h:commandButton or equivalent to ouput <button> HTML output?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way for JSF to output something like this:

```
<button type="submit" ...></button>
```

I know that you are supposed to use `<:hcommandButton />` normally but it outputs a `<input type="submit">` instead and the front end developer wants to put a `<i />` inside the button to have icons inside using font awesome.

Would be great if we could avoid using a custom component...it's pretty tedious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the [`<h:button>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/h/button.html).

```
<h:button value="Label" outcome="page.xhtml" />
```

PrimeFaces has a more customizeable one as [`<p:button>`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/button.xhtml).

Note that you can also just write down plain HTML in JSF and if necessary just wrap it in a composite component or a tag file.

#### See also:

- [Faces 4.0 View Declaration Language Documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/)

Answer (score 0):

<h:button> output is `<input type="button">` and not `<button>` output in HTML